# Node.js Wit.ai promise return function

Tags: javascript, node.js, wit.ai, wit-ai

My promise return undefined values. I'm not sure how I can perform this function correctly in my node.js page. Could you please help me with this in order to return all values AFTER geocoding in my context in  good way! Thank you

```
merge_location({
    entities,
    context,
    message,
    sessionId
}) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var location = firstEntityValue(entities, 'location');
        if (location) {
            geocoder.geocode(location).then(function(res) {
                console.log(res);
                context.location = location;
                context.lat = res[0].latitude;
                context.lng = res[0].longitude;
                delete context.MissingLocation;
            }).catch(function(err) {
                context.MissingLocation = true;
                delete context.location;
                delete context.lat;
                delete context.lng;
                console.log("Il n'y a pas de ville ");
            });
        } else {
            context.MissingLocation = true;
            delete context.location;
            delete context.lat;
            delete context.lng;
            console.log("Il n'y a pas de ville ");
        }
        console.log("I want to return this" + context.location + ' ' + context.lat + ' ' + context.lng);
        return resolve(context);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to say `return resolve(...`. Instead you just call `resolve(...`

For example:

```
function myPromiseFunction(x) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        // Do your lengthy processing with x here

        if (everyThingLooksGood) {
            resolve(thingYouWantToReturn);
        } else {
            reject("ERROR: Things didn't go according to plan!");
        }
    });
}
```